# Creating a url regex to parse domain name

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, expression

I need to create a regex that identify a string if that is a url with my criteria but i got stuck in identifying the domain name...

the criteria for domain name is

1. only `[a-z][0-9]`, `.` and `-`
2. first char must be `[a-z]`
3. before and after `.` or `-` must be `[a-z]`
4. min length 1 char

and the domain region is

1. only `[a-z]` and `.`
2. first char must be `.`
3. min length 3 char

format should be `www.<domain name>.<domain region>`

here what i got..

```
www.[a-z]([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,}[a-z][\.\-])+[^\.+\-].[a-z+\.]{2,}[^\.]$
```

this is for the domain name

```
[a-z]([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,}[a-z][\.\-])+[^\.+\-]
```

this is for the domain region

```
.[a-z+\.]{2,}[^\.]$
```

this will be `www.sample.com.sg`

- `www..sample.com` will be rejected because of `.sample`
- `www.sample..com` will be rejected because of `sample.`
- `www.sample.com.sg.` will be rejected because of `.com.sg.`
- `www.sampl3.sample.com` will be rejected because of `sampl3.` rules numb 3.

Comment: here is a start: `www\.[a-z]([.-][a-z]|[a-z0-9])+`

Comment: are you sure about rule 3? What is wrong with `all-4-one.com`?

Comment: thx.. 4 ur fast response.. but at the end of domain name, it can't be a '.' or '-'.. how can i validate that? err.. i don't think this is a great criteria for identifying a url, but i got a assignment and this is the criteria my lecturer give.. so thats why..ahahahhaa..xD

Comment: it is only a start. It should take you up to the TLD - but not with your extra rule about only letters around hyphens.

Comment: hahaha.. yes.. that's true.. with this extra rules this can't be TLD..@_@

Answer (score 3):

Reinvent not

- URI.js: http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/
- URL parser: https://gist.github.com/2428561

Things like this have been done so many times, it's better to leverage the existing code than to relearn all the URL rules and spec requirements.

Comment: yes.. that's will be a great way to identify the url in easier way..but i have to go with the regex.. so thx for answering..:D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out: **^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$**
I haven't pretested it, so few regulations may be necessary

Comment: hmm.. i've seen that code before.. but i have to go with that criteria i described above..anyway thanks for answering..:D

Comment: com/org etc fails to match anything outside the US; .eu, .co.uk, .it. It will even fail with common things like .me, bit.ly etc.

Comment: yes.. and that's only for the domain name that u mentioned (com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU).. other than that will fail

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
www\.(([a-z][a-z0-9]*)?[a-z][\.\-])*([a-z][a-z0-9]*)?[a-z]\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

Crazy long so maybe there's better ones but...

Comment: Yeah i missed the that the domain name must start with [a-z] but was it more than that? I'll edit the regExp.

Comment: Missed the [a-z] before and after [\.\-] part to

Comment: ahahha... yes.. and the last of domain name cannot be a . or -.. and there cant be numbers before . and -..@_@

Comment: what if it's like this [a-z]([a-z]+[0-9]*[a-z]+|[\.\-])+

Comment: i dont really get what ? means??.. @@

Comment: ? == {0,1} in this reqexp but it can also be used to make quantifiers non-greedy. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark)